# problem with php version in composer.json

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, localhost

im trying to do `composer upgrade` on this laravel project, in the composer.json it seems to use packages that require php 7.3

[image: the problem]

in my xampp i have two php versions, the default one is php 8.2.0 (on port 80)

[image: php 8.2.0]

the other one is php 7.3 (on port 8056)

[image: php 7.3]

**how do i get it so that it uses php 7.3 in this project?**

Comment: if you are using windows os then you have to add you xamm path on it which version you want to use. After declaring the path please restart you pc then remove you composer.lock file and run composer install or composer install --ignore-platform-reqs.

Comment: im sorry, could you reiterate where to do what? im kind of lost here

Comment: to set xampp in environment variable please check this link : https://dinocajic.medium.com/add-xampp-php-to-environment-variables-in-windows-10-af20a765b0ce . after set up you variable for specific php version please restart your oc then remove composer.lock and vendor folder. then run composer install hope this will work

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem